# Find the final redirected url using Python

Tags: http, url, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to use python to find the final redirected URL for a url. I tried various solutions from stackoverflow answers but nothing worked for me. I am only getting the original url.

To be specific, I tried `requests`, `urllib2` and `urlparse` libraries and none of them worked as they should. Here are some of the codes I tried:

**Solution 1:**

```
s = requests.session()
r = s.post('https://www.boots.com/search/10055096', allow_redirects=True)
print(r.history)
print(r.history[1].url)
```

**Result:**

```
[<Response [301]>, <Response [302]>]
https://www.boots.com/search/10055096
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import urlparse
url = 'https://www.boots.com/search/10055096'
try:
    out = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)['out'][0]
    print(out)
except Exception as e:
    print('not found')
```

**Result:**
`not found`

**Solution 3:**

```
import urllib2
def get_redirected_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url
print(get_redirected_url('https://www.boots.com/search/10055096'))
```

**Result:**

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

Expected URL below is the final redirected page and that is what I want to return.

**Original URL:** `https://www.boots.com/search/10055096`

**Expected URL:** `https://www.boots.com/gillette-fusion5-razor-blades-4pk-10055096`

Solution #1 was the closest one. At least it returned 2 responses but second respond wasn't the final page, it seems like it was the loading page looking at the content of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first request returns with a html file which contains a JS to update the site and Java scripts are not processed by `requests` . You can find the updated link by using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.boots.com/search/10055096')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
reg = soup.find('input',id='searchBoxText').findNext('script').contents[0]
print(re.search(r'ht[\w\://\.-]+', reg).group())
```